# Create an SVG path (w/ arrow) connecting to a circle element

Tags: svg, react-flow

I've got a graph where source and target elements ('nodes') are circular and the connection between these two (an 'edge') must be an arrow, starting in the center of the source node and pointing to the **edge** of the target circle. I do have exact coordinates of both source and target nodes (center of the circle) and know the radius of the target node. Connecting them (path starting in the center of the source circle and ending in the center of the target circle) is pretty straight forward: `M ${sourceX},${sourceY} L ${targetX - 50},${targetY}`: [image]
but can't wrap my head around the algo behind the actual desired result: (please note the target node can be moved around)
[image]

Thanks!

semi-related link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724792/an-algorithm-for-finding-the-intersection-point-between-a-center-of-vision-and-a

Comment: Find the angle of the line. Trigonometry will tell you where on the radius it intercepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to calculate the angle of the arrow:

`let angle = Math.atan2(source.y - target.y, source.x - target.x);`

Next you calculate the position of the tip of the arrow as a point on a circle with the center in the target center and the radius R = radius of the target + width of the marker.

```
let p = { x: target.x + R * Math.cos(angle), 
          y: target.y + R * Math.sin(angle)};
```

Please read the comments in my code:

```js
let s = { x: 10, y: -32, r:2 }; //source
let t = { x: -70, y: -85, r:4 }; //target


//set the source and target attributes
source.setAttribute("cx", s.x);
source.setAttribute("cy", s.y);
source.setAttribute("r", s.r);
target.setAttribute("cx", t.x);
target.setAttribute("cy", t.y);
target.setAttribute("r", t.r);


//the tip of the arrow must be on the target edge so you need to take in consideration the marker wudth
let R = t.r + Number(mk.getAttribute("markerWidth"));

let a = Math.atan2(s.y - t.y, s.x - t.x); //the angle
// the point where the path ends
let p = { x: t.x + R * Math.cos(a), y: t.y + R * Math.sin(a) };
//set thed attribute of the arrow.
arrow.setAttribute("d", `M${s.x},${s.y}L${p.x},${p.y}`);
```

```css
path{marker-end:url(#mk);}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
  <marker id="mk" viewBox="0 0 4 4" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" refX="0" refY="2" orient="auto" fill="red">
    <polygon points="0,0 4,2 0,4" />
  </marker>
  <circle r="2" id="source" />
  <circle r="4" id="target" />

  <path id="arrow" stroke="red" d="M10,25L70,45" />
</svg>
```